# How To render calendar view header programmatically

Tags: 7, views, datetime

[image]I am using Page calendar and I want to print calendar view header in a different block. How can I achieve this?

Comment: [views_embed_view](https://api.drupal.org/views_embed_view) should do the job. e.g. `views_embed_view('VIEWS_MACHINE_NAME', 'DISPLAY_ID', $view_arg);`

Comment: I want to display calendar  header which is shown in the image

Comment: There is no image attached in question. Please update your question with required details.

Comment: Image uploaded please check

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have a `view` of type `page` that shows calendar. But you want that calendar to be rendered in a block. And this block you want in your header.

So, for this, click on `advanced` section in views. There you will see 
EXPOSED FORM
Exposed form in block:No

Click on `No` and make it yes. Check your blocks, a block of this view will get created. Now with the help of `page.tpl.php`, render this block in your header section.

Or simply assign this block to 'header' region if you already have header region managed in your tpl file.

[image]

Comment: no I want to show only the month name pager  which is left side of the image ,in the block.